# Certificate Error when deploying Application with Traefik

Tags: reverse-proxy, traefik

I have my application running using Visual Studio (technically, iisexpress) on windows.  I am able to successfully test that my application is accessible through http://localhost:5100 and https://localhost:7254 (the certificate was automatically created by Visual Studio just for dev/testing purposes).

Following is the script I used to test above website using traefik:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:2.0
    command:
      - "--providers.file.filename=/etc/traefik/proxy-config.toml"
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - ./proxy-config.toml:/etc/traefik/proxy-config.toml:ro
```

and the proxy-config.toml is as follows:

```
[serversTransport]
  insecureSkipVerify = true

[api]
  insecure = true
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[http.routers]
  [http.routers.app-website]
    rule = "Host(`test.localhost`)"
    service = "app-website-http"
    entryPoints = ["http"]
  [http.routers.app-website-https]
    rule = "Host(`test.localhost`)"
    service = "app-website-https"
    entryPoints = ["https"]
    [http.routers.app-website-https.tls]
      certResolver = "tlsresolver"

[http.services]
  [http.services.app-website-http.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.app-website-http.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://host.docker.internal:5100"
  [http.services.app-website-https.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.app-website-https.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "https://host.docker.internal:7254"

[certificatesResolvers]
  [certificatesResolvers.tlsresolver.acme]
    email = "jag@test.com"
    storage = "./acme.json"
    [certificatesResolvers.tlsresolver.acme.httpChallenge]
      entryPoint = "http"
    [certificatesResolvers.tlsresolver.acme.tlsChallenge]
```

I modified hosts file to redirect test.localhost to 127.0.0.1.  The above works fine for "http" and with no issues (i.e., redirects http://test.localhost to http://localhost:5100 with no issues).  However, it fails for "https".  It first throws certificate error (Your connection is not privite) and proceeding ahead I experience "Internal Server Error".

I would like to make use of "auto ssl certificate creation" feature of traefik and ensure redirection to my https://localhost:7254.  In simple, if I browse to https://test.localhost, it has to redirect to https://localhost:7254.

Being novice to traefik, I am not sure how to enable/check for traefik logs (or traefik dashboard) using above script.  Appreciate your help!

**UPDATE**:

I learnt that we would need resolvable host name.  I shifted my gears to have a self-signed certificate for the deployment (just for dev/testing).  I used "mkcert" to generate cert and key files.  I modified script as follows:

```
version: "3.7"
services:

  proxy:
    image: traefik:2.0
    command:
      - "--entrypoints.http.address=:80"
      - "--entrypoints.https.address=:443"
      - "--providers.file.directory=/configuration/"
      - "--providers.file.filename=/configuration/proxy-config.toml"
      - "--providers.file.watch=true"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./configuration/:/configuration/"
      - ./configuration/proxy-config.toml:/configuration/proxy-config.toml:ro
```

and the toml file as follows:

```
[serversTransport]
  insecureSkipVerify = true

[api]
  insecure = true
  dashboard = true
  debug = true

[http.routers]
  [http.routers.app-website]
    rule = "Host(`test.localhost`)"
    service = "app-website-http"
    entryPoints = ["http"]
    
  [http.routers.app-website-https]
    rule = "Host(`test.localhost`)"
    service = "app-website-https"
    entryPoints = ["https"]
    [http.routers.app-website-https.tls]      

[http.services]
  [http.services.app-website-http.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.app-website-http.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "http://host.docker.internal:5100"
  [http.services.app-website-https.loadBalancer]
    [[http.services.app-website-https.loadBalancer.servers]]
      url = "https://host.docker.internal:7254"

#[[tls.certificates]]
#  certFile = "/configuration/certs/cert.pem"
#  keyFile = "/configuration/certs/key.pem"

[tls.stores]
  [tls.stores.default]
    [tls.stores.default.defaultCertificate]
      certFile = "/configuration/certs/cert.pem"
      keyFile = "/configuration/certs/key.pem"
```

I created configuration folder in current path and dumped all artifacts.  "http" works fine and I still face the same error with "https"

Answer (score 2):

If you are hoping to use an ACME certificate provider like Let's Encrypt, you need to follow [these instructions](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/https/acme/). Note that for this to work you need to be using a resolvable hostname -- that is, a name that exists in DNS that can be resolved by the Let's Encrypted certificate issuers. `test.localhost` is not going to be resolvable from anywhere other than your local system.

Comment: hi @larsks.  Thanks for the comment.  You are right.  I just learned that resolvable hostname is a must.  I modified my code to use self-signed certificate and I still face error.